# Slick Slider - unexpected behaviour - shows all the slides for a split second when loading

Tags: javascript, slick.js

I'm trying to implement this slider into my website, but there is something very annoying that I can't find the solution for.
Please click the button RUN THE SNIPPET a few times and see that there are all 3 slides showing for a split second right after the page is loaded. Very annoying and can't find any solution in official docs. But hope there is an solution for this problem.

```js
        $(document).ready(() => {
            $('#slider .slick').slick({
                autoplay: true,
                infinite: true,
                speed: 1000,
                autoplaySpeed: 2000,
                slidesToShow: 1,
                slidesToScroll: 1,
                arrows: false,
                dots: false,
                fade: true,
                pauseOnFocus: false,
                pauseOnHover: false,
            });
        });
```

```css
.slide {
  text-align: center;
}
.slide p {
  font-size: 45px;
  font-weight: 600;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.css"/>


<div class="slick-slider" id="slider">
    <div class="slick-slider__wrapper slick">
        <div class="slide"><p>THIS IS SIMPLE</p></div>
        <div class="slide"><p>SLICK SLIDER</p></div>
        <div class="slide"><p>TEST</p></div>
    </div>
</div>
    
    
<script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.1.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-o88AwQnZB+VDvE9tvIXrMQaPlFFSUTR+nldQm1LuPXQ="
    crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
```